# Vaadin: upgraded from v18 to v21: web ui does not load

Tags: vaadin, vaadin21

I upgraded an existing (and working!) Vaadin application that was using v18.0.2 to v21.0.4. With that new version the server side application starts up as usual, it initializes OK and the first requests triggers the frontend compilation (which also seems to work OK, at least the log shows no abnormalities or errors), but the UI just hangs and fails to load (there is a thin blue progress bar at the top of the page which quickly reaches about 50% of the width, then it gets slower and slower and then starves at about 90% of the screen width).

I don't have the slightest clue in which direction I should check or analyze this. Any suggestion or hint what could be wrong here would be highly appreciated!

If I should attach any config or log details to help analyzing this let me know!

Later addendum:
I attach my `vaadin_dance.cmd` here:

```
@echo off

:package_entries
set fn=package.json
echo Step 1: Going to remove unsupported Vaadin v19+ entries from %fn%:
pause
rem let user see what we do:
@echo on
type %fn%   | findstr /V /C:"@vaadin/application-theme-plugin" > %fn%_1
type %fn%_1 | findstr /V /C:"@vaadin/stats-plugin"             > %fn%_2
type %fn%_2 | findstr /V /C:"@vaadin/theme-live-reload-plugin" > %fn%_3
type %fn%_3 | findstr /V /C:"@vaadin/theme-loader"             > %fn%_4
rem remove an already existing backup - just in case (if there were one the cp below won't work)
rm %fn%~
rem rename back to original and keep a backup:
cp -b -f %fn%_4 %fn%
rem delete the temp. files":
rm %fn%_?
@echo off
echo unsupported Vaadin v19+ entries removed from %fn%

:local_stuff
echo Step 2: Going to remove project local stuff:
pause
rem let user see what we do:
@echo on
rmdir /S /Q .\target
rmdir /S /Q .\node_modules
rmdir /S /Q .\frontend\generated
rm package.json
rm package-lock.json
rm pnpm-lock.yaml
rm pnpmfile.js
rm tsconfig.json
rm types.d.ts
rm webpack.config.js
rm webpack.generated.js
@echo off
echo project local vaadin-generated stuff removed.

:global_stuff
echo Step 3: Going to remove global stuff: removing pnpm stuff
pause
rem let user see what we do:
@echo on
rm -r -f %USERPROFILE%\.pnpm-debug.log
rm -r -f %USERPROFILE%\.pnpm-state.json
rmdir /S /Q %USERPROFILE%\.vaadin
rmdir /S /Q %USERPROFILE%\.pnpm-store
rem just in case - I encountered them here, too:
rmdir /S /Q D:\.pnpm-store
rmdir /S /Q U:\.pnpm-store
@echo off
echo global vaadin-installed stuff removed.
rem clear (and preload) default repository:

:repo_stuff
echo Step 4: Going to empty m2repository!
pause
rem let user see what we do:
@echo on
rem strange enough I again and again got "access denied" on certain .jars ||-(  So we first take ownership...
takeown /R /F %USERPROFILE%\.m2\m2repository
rem ... before removing the stuff:
rm -r -f %USERPROFILE%\.m2\m2repository\*
@echo off
echo m2repository cleaned.
echo.
pause
```

The process with the above .cmd file is such, that I run first step 1, then I stop it and try to rebuildv(in a different cmd window). If that does not work, I restart it from begin and run steps 1 & 2, then I stop and try to rebuild, etc. At most after steps 1, 2, 3 & 4 I was (at least so far) always able to rebuild and execute my application. That's at least when build with or reverting to  v18.0.3. With v21.x I haven't been successful so far. :-(

Second addendum with the console output:

The application starts up OK (i.e. without any error message( up to the point where I see "Tomcat has been started on port: ..."

At that point I direct my browser to that port which triggers the dispatching of the DispatcherServlet. That page never loads and the browser times out, but there is NO error message or anything giving a hint re. the type or cause of the problem on the console:

```
...
2021-12-17 19:36:03,459 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer: Tomcat started on port(s): 8085 (http) with context path ''
2021-12-17 19:36:23,678 INFO  [http-nio-8085-exec-1] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-12-17 19:36:23,682 INFO  [http-nio-8085-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet: Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-12-17 19:36:23,689 INFO  [http-nio-8085-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet: Completed initialization in 2 ms
2021-12-17 19:36:26,103 WARN  [http-nio-8085-exec-1] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [2,172] milliseconds.
2021-12-17 19:36:26,103 WARN  [http-nio-8085-exec-3] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [1,457] milliseconds.
2021-12-17 19:36:26,179 INFO  [http-nio-8085-exec-4] com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator: The number of beans implementing 'I18NProvider' is 0. Cannot use Spring beans for I18N, falling back to the default behavior
<Console output stops here and browser times out>
```

Unfortunately there seems no way to attach screenshots here, so I can't provide the output of the WebDeveloper's Network Tab's output here...

The Browser Inspector Console displays:

```
Fri Dec 17 2021 19:52:01 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) Atmosphere: unload event vaadinPush-min.js:1:40213
Vaadin push loaded vaadinPush-min.js:1:44231
Failed to register/update a ServiceWorker for scope ‘http://localhost:8085/’: Bad Content-Type of ‘text/html’ received for script ‘sw-runtime-resources-precache.js’.  Must be a JavaScript MIME type.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ServiceWorker script at http://localhost:8085/sw.js for scope http://localhost:8085/ threw an exception during script evaluation.
Path '/login' is not properly resolved due to an error. Resolution had failed on route: '(.*)' vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58:17000
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: class heritage e is not an object or null
    to http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-3-1a44b245d20aa3c33130.cache.js:1
    266 http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-3-1a44b245d20aa3c33130.cache.js:765
    r http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:1
    promise callback*imports http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    flowInit http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    async*get action/< http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    Z http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    __resolveRoute http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    promise callback*__resolveRoute http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    resolveRoute http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    a http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    a http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    promise callback*a http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    resolve http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    promise callback*resolve http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    render http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    __onNavigationEvent http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    setRoutes http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:58
    r http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:1
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:1
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8085/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-aec7d8b0cb06e0cbb6bd.cache.js:1
vaadin-3-1a44b245d20aa3c33130.cache.js:1:153
```

​
How is a non-Vaadin intern supposed to decode that stuff and analyse what's going wrong here?

Comment: Which side starves? server or client? what does the log say (server or dev tools)? do you have server side code, that would lend itself to a deadlock?

Comment: With "starving" I meant the client's progress bar (the blue line on top of the page that indicates page loading). The server side logs says nothing special. The first request triggers the usual frontend compilation but there is no error shown (I doubt that displaying that part of the log here helps a lot or would it?). Re. dead-locks: of course one can never exclude that but I don't think so. I never had any in my application. And the hanging was really triggered by just updating the vaadin version number and rebuilding. Before that it worked fine, since then it doesn't anymore.

Comment: I forgot to add: that "starving" happens already when loading the login-page. It's almost as if the UI-server isn't listening.

Comment: Can you try "mvn vaadin:clean-frontend" and then try again?

Comment: After executing that command I now always get: `Could not execute build-frontend goal: Couldn't remove <project>\node_modules directory: Unable to delete file: <project>\node_modules: <project>\node_modules\.pnpm\@babel\core@7.16.0\node_modules\@babel\code-frame -> [Help 1]`. Time for a vaadin-dance - I guess...

Comment: The Vaadin dance didn't help! I then reverted the version back to v18.0.3, did another Vaadin dance - the app worked again. Then I changed the version forward to v21.0.4 again, yet another Vaadin dance and a complete rebuild - same error again: the UI just doesn't load! :-(

Comment: Did you try with only removing the `node_modules` folder? `vaadin:clean-frontend` is the same as the vaadin dance from mavis blog post, but less destructive for user changes, but it sometimes fails to clean node_modules.

Comment: Just tested the base starter with jump from 18.0.7 to 21.0.4 and there was no problems. Are you using CDI or Spring? is there anything in the logs for webpack or npm/pnpm when starting? Also does this happen both for building in development mode and production mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded to v22.0.1. With that new version my application now loads again! Beats me what was broken in versions 19.0.x - 21.0.4 that caused my application's UI to not load.

But there are still one issue:

The initial page is not the application's main-page but some odd `self-additionalManifestEntries`-page (see my append
[Vaadin v22: Odd page displayed each time after login to application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70472101/vaadin-v22-odd-page-displayed-each-time-after-login-to-application)). I always need to reload the main page to enter my actual application.

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue replicated and the problem is that in development mode I got a `400 (Bad Request)` in the console from `Flow.ts` with the faulty response `Error 400 Invalid location: Location parameter missing from bootstrap request to server.`

The fix was to delete the `./frontend/generated` folder after which the application worked as it should when running `mvn clean jetty:run`. But the `vaadin:clean-frontend` goal should remove the `generated` folder in `frontend` which at least for me was the problem.

Check the inspector and look if there is any exceptions in the console.

Comment: Unfortunately cleaning out the `./frontend/generated` directory did not help here. That was already part of my `vaadin_dance.cmd` (which I attached for reference). 
Is there anything else that might need to be cleaned?

Comment: Did you check in the browser inspector console if there is an exception thrown and what that might be?

Comment: I added the inspector console's output as well.