# Vaadin v22: Odd page displayed each time after login to application

Tags: vaadin, vaadin22

Since upgrading to Vaadin 22 each time after log into my Vaadin app I am displayed a page that reads:

```
self.additionalManifestEntries = [
{ url: 'icons/icon-144x144.png', revision: '456714318' },
{ url: 'icons/icon-192x192.png', revision: '-1481948590' },
{ url: 'icons/icon-512x512.png', revision: '789785684' },
{ url: 'icons/icon-16x16.png', revision: '1782914653' },
{ url: 'icons/icon-32x32.png', revision: '-208588914' },
{ url: 'offline-stub.html', revision: '1882808088' },
{ url: 'manifest.webmanifest', revision: '-502500014' },
{ url: './styles/offline.css', revision: '2113525300' },
{ url: './images/offline.png', revision: '2113525300' }
];
```

I had this already once before when switching from v18 to v20 (see [Vaadin v20 and new also with v22: Odd page displayed each time after login to application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67936187/vaadin-v20-and-new-also-with-v22-odd-page-displayed-each-time-after-login-to-ap)) and I then switched from a self-written `CustomRequestCache` to the then new `VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and `VaadinDefaultRequestCache`.

So, what is it this time, that causing this again? Do I need to switch this again?
Did I miss something?